# A way to strip returned values from java.io.File.listFiles in Clojure

Tags: java, file, clojure, lisp, io

I call a java function in Clojure to get a list of files.

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(str (.listFiles (io/file "/home/loluser/loldir")))
```

And I get a whole bunch of strings like these

```
#<File /home/loluser/loldir/lolfile1>
```

etc. How do I get rid of the brackets and put them in some form of an array so another function can access it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those strings are just the print format for a Java `File` object.

See the [File javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for which operations are available.

If you want the file paths as strings, it would be something like

```
(map #(.getPath %) 
  (.listFiles (io/file "/home/loluser/loldir")))
```

Or you could just use `list`, which returns strings in the first place:

```
(.list (io/file "/home/loluser/loldir"))
```

If you want to read the file, you might as well keep it as a File object to pass into the core `slurp` or other clojure.java.io or [clojure.contrib.duck-streams](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/duck-streams-api.html) functions.

Comment: Could I pass the File object to slurp like this: (slurp (first (.listFiles (io/file "/home/loluser/loldir")))) or maybe put it into a var first and then do a slurp of the var?

Comment: Yes. Although listFiles returns both files and directories, so you would probably want to filter with #(.isFile %) first.

Comment: Is there a way to sort the files in the map by lastModified date?

Comment: Sure: `(sort-by #(.lastModified %)
         (.listFiles (io/file "/etc")))` http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/sort-by